# Prevent socket.io client from attempting to connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I had implemented socket.io for a service and have since removed it. However, I still have clients making initial connection requests to the the endpoint /socket.io, which no longer exists. Responding with various http status codes doesn't seem to matter.

Is there a way to prevent a client from attempting to connect? I'm receiving thousands of requests per minute.

Comment: You have to update the client code if possible. So it stops doing that. But even that may not be enough, since you cannot actually force code update. You've basically DDOSed yourself and in worse case scenario (no control over client) you can only block the incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to modify the client to disable the socket.io code. Apart from that, no, socket.io does not have a special "halt and catch fire" signal that you could send to clients to prevent them from trying again.

If, for some reason, you can't update the clients, you should block the path at a higher layer - depending on how your app is deployed, this could be a cloud load balancer, a Web Application Firewall, or perhaps a haproxy instance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you removed a service endpoint (the socket.io endpoint) from your servers without first updating your clients out there in the wide world.

That was, with respect, a mistake. It's a common mistake; upgrading servers and clients in sync is difficult.  Usually we deprecate features: we leave them in servers for backward compatibility until all clients cease using them.

I guess your client code, when socket.io connection attempts fail, retries those attempts. So your servers are being bombarded with retries. Your immediate fix is to put back the socket.io endpoint so the connection attempts succeed. That will get rid of the flood of retries. You don't have to do anything with those socket.io connections after you accept them.

Then, you need to figure out how to update your client code in the field to stop using your deprecated socket.io server feature.